# How to get several records to be shown in one row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger, django-database-functions

I have questions related to SELECT statement for this case:
For example there are 4 tables, which are StdCandidate, CourseChoice, Course, and EntranceTest.

The tables are shown in the image 
-->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoZtp.png)

Can you help me what is the query to get the **expected query**?

the image that I shared there is expected result of the query. I dont know how to get 1stChoice and 2ndChoice and also Test(234) and Test(123) in the same row (one record)

Comment: You never told us what is the expected query, but in any case you most likely need to _join_ your tables together.

Comment: The tables and also expected result for the query are in the image attached, Sir. @TimBiegeleisen


I dont know how to get 1stChoice and 2ndChoice and also Test(234) and Test(123) in the same row (one record)
I hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: Load the stuff in a sqlfiddle and spare us the 1hour to type it in

Answer (score 0):

you should check that realtionship because there is no way to relate an exam to a course, so it is not posible to tell what course belong to what exam.

this query should get you some of the data but as i said there is no real relation with the exams and courses, if there where a field named ExamCode in CourseChoose it would be quite easy to pivot the data then. thoug mysql cant do that but a procedure would just fine.

```
select a.id_exam,a.name, c.description,d.examcode,d.total
from stdcandidate a, coursechoose b, course c, entrancetest d
where a.id_exam = b.id_exam
  and b.id_course = c.CourseCode
  and a.id_exam = d.id_exam
  /*and d.examcode = b.ExamCode  --this doesnt exists*/;
```

Comment: In the image that I shared there is expected result of the query. I dont know how to get 1stChoice and 2ndChoice and also Test(234) and Test(123) in the same row (one record)